# Return all null values between two dates

Tags: oracle

I have the following query and I need it to return all the null values between those two dates.

```
select cust_first_name
from customers
join orders using(customer_id)
where order_date between (to_date('01-01-2007','DD-MM-YYYY'))
                     and (to_date('31-12-2008','DD-MM-YYYY'));
```

Comment: null values of what column? Do you need the count of those? (A list of nulls isn't particularly interesting.)

Comment: I need the first name of the clients that have no registered orders between those to dates. Its the null value of the column order_date.

Comment: If that column is null, it can't fall between two dates. You need to base your search on other criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like what you want is customers with no orders within the given date range.  The join you are using finds the opposite of that.

You could do this with an outer join, in which case you need to apply the date filter prior to the join.  It's probably easier and more readable to use a NOT IN or NOT EXISTS subquery:

```
select cust_first_name
from customers
WHERE customers.customer_id NOT IN (
  SELECT orders.customer_id from orders
  where order_date between (to_date('01-01-2007','DD-MM-YYYY'))
                       and (to_date('31-12-2008','DD-MM-YYYY'))
)
```

Comment: This is what I needed I just didn't know to explain myself! Thank you very much!

Comment: This won't work if `ORDERS.customer_id` has a `NULL` value in it. In that case you'll want to use `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of how to do what you want.

The key part is doing a left join on your orders table, and then simply doing a not between date1 and date2

```
declare @customers table (
    id int identity(1,1),
    first_name nvarchar(50),
    last_name nvarchar(50)
)

declare @orders table (
    id int identity(1,1),
    customer_id int,
    order_date datetime
)

insert into @customers(first_name, last_name) values ('bob', 'gates')
insert into @customers(first_name, last_name) values ('cyril', 'smith')
insert into @customers(first_name, last_name) values ('harry', 'potter')

insert into @orders(customer_id, order_date) values (1, '2007-02-01')
insert into @orders(customer_id, order_date) values (2, '2015-02-15')
insert into @orders(customer_id, order_date) values (3, '2008-02-15')

select
     customers.id
    ,customers.first_name
    ,customers.last_name
from @customers customers
    left join @orders orders on orders.customer_id = customers.id
where orders.id is null
    or orders.order_date not between ('2007-01-01') and ('2008-12-31')
group by
     customers.id
    ,customers.first_name
    ,customers.last_name;
```

Comment: I don't think a SQL Server solution will do the OP much good.